# How did Reiner Braun capture Eren?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In the end of Episode 7 Season 2 of Attack on Titan, Eren was about to break Reiner Braun's neck.

Then following that event, the Colossus Titan starts to fall, we see a shot that seems to show that Reiner is above Eren and has grabbed him, and later we hear that Reiner captured Eren.

What happened in the middle and how did Reiner Braun capture Eren?

Comment: spoiler title, you really should change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the Colossus Titan (Bertholdt) fell on both of them, the Armored Titan (Reiner) bit Eren's Titan form in the neck. That was how he got Eren out from his Titan form.

Comment: Nice answer, but try to add a bit more context, links, or a few more lines. Anything less that 3 or 4 sentences from new users tend to get downvoted here. So please keep that in mind.

Comment: Also, the armored titan has armor (duh!), so he took less damage from the falling colossal titan than eren did.

Comment: Is it really necessary to capitalize every single word?

Comment: To elaborate on the answer: This is proven by the beginning of the next episode, where Reiner apologizes to Eren about losing his arms. Reiner says that he forgot to account for Eren's arms (amidst the fighting) when biting him out of Eren's Titan, thus biting them off.

Answer (score 2):

Spoilers here on episodes 7 and 8 of Attack on Titan (anime), and the 45th chapter of Attack on Titan (manga).

> Towards the end of the battle between Eren and Reiner (Armored Titan) that occurred in episode 7 of Season 2 of Attack on Titan, we see Eren place Reiner in a special hold wherein Reiner's head is trapped within Eren's arms. Unable to break this hold, Reiner calls out to Bertolt (Colossal Titan) three separate times. At that point, Bertolt falls over and we later see that Eren is captured. Episode 8 of Season 2 provides some information as to why Eren lost his arms after this fight, but doesn't shed light on the actual events that led to Eren being captured.

If you reference back to the same place in the manga,

> We find out that when Reiner called for Bertolt, the Colossal Titan's "plan" so-to-speak was to literally fall on top of both Eren and Reiner because only Reiner as the Armored Titan would be able to withstand the force of impact. The force of impact was so strong that the body of the Colossal Titan evaporated once he landed on the other two titans, and it blew a large gust of heat and wind pressure straight up the wall which prevented anyone from going down to help Eren. Since Reiner was the only titan capable of withstanding that impact, he was then able to pull Eren from from the nape of Eren's neck because the force of impact left Eren incapacitated.